# dartfmt and matrix array

Tags: dart, dartfmt

The dart format converts

```dart
const ColorFilter greyscale = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0,
  0,      0,      0,      1, 0,
]);
```

to

```dart
const ColorFilter greyscale = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
  0.2126,
  0.7152,
  0.0722,
  0,
  0,
  0.2126,
  0.7152,
  0.0722,
  0,
  0,
  0.2126,
  0.7152,
  0.0722,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
]);
```

and makes it more unreadable, is it possible somehow tell dart formatter that ignore formatting this part of code?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-does-the-formatter-mess-up-my-collection-literals

Comment: @jamesdlin Smart solution! WOW!